# Getting "Incorrectly ordered" error message when setting a folder permission to a domain group using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file-permissions, acl, ntfs

I am trying to set permissions to a folder via Powershell Following is the code:

```
$acl = Get-Acl $folderPath
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)

$ruleOwner = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($group,"Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($ruleOwner)

Set-Acl $folderPath $acl
```

Once I ran this code and try to open the Security tab of the concerned folder, I am getting the error message:

> > The permissions on [folder name] are incorrectly ordered, which may cause some entries to be ineffective.

What is the correct way to set permission on a folder to a specific group?

Comment: take a look at >>> windows - What causes "The permissions on <folder> are incorrectly ordered"? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506297/what-causes-the-permissions-on-folder-are-incorrectly-ordered <<< it seems that you need the `DENY` privs all set before any `ALLOW` privs.

Comment: Try using `inherit` privileges before `modify`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access rules (ACEs) need to be [ordered in a certain way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/order-of-aces-in-a-dacl) inside an ACL.
Basically, the order is

1. All explicit ACEs are placed in a group before any inherited ACEs.
2. Within the group of explicit ACEs, access-denied ACEs are placed before access-allowed ACEs.
3. Inherited ACEs are placed in the order in which they are inherited. ACEs inherited from the child object's parent come first, then ACEs inherited from the grandparent, and so on up the tree of objects.
4. For each level of inherited ACEs, access-denied ACEs are placed before access-allowed ACEs.

If this order somehow gets mixed-up, you will see the "Permissions incorrectly ordered" error message.

To rearrange the order of the permissions, you could use the below function:

```
function Repair-DirectoryPermissions {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [string]$Path
    )

    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $Path
    # create a new empty ACL object
    $newAcl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity

    # copy the access rules from the existing ACL to the new one in the correct order
    # first the explicit DENY rules
    $acl.Access | Where-Object { !$_.IsInherited -and $_.AccessControlType -eq 'Deny' } | ForEach-Object {
        $newAcl.AddAccessRule($_)
    }
    # next the explicit ALLOW rules
    $acl.Access | Where-Object { !$_.IsInherited -and $_.AccessControlType -eq 'Allow' } | ForEach-Object {
        $newAcl.AddAccessRule($_)
    }
    # finally the inherited rules
    $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.IsInherited } | ForEach-Object {
        $newAcl.AddAccessRule($_)
    }

    # set the the reordered ACL to the directory object
    Set-Acl -Path $Path -AclObject $newAcl
}
```

And use it like:

```
Repair-DirectoryPermissions -Path 'D:\Blah'
```

While doing this, you may get an exception telling you that you need the `SeSecurityPrivilege` permission to perform this action.
To get that, add another function on top of the script:

```
function Enable-Privilege {
    [CmdletBinding(ConfirmImpact = 'low', SupportsShouldProcess = $false)]  
    [OutputType('System.Boolean')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateSet(
            "SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege", "SeAuditPrivilege", "SeBackupPrivilege", "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege", 
            "SeCreateGlobalPrivilege", "SeCreatePagefilePrivilege", "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege", 
            "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege", "SeCreateTokenPrivilege", "SeDebugPrivilege", "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege", 
            "SeImpersonatePrivilege", "SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege", "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege", 
            "SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege", "SeLoadDriverPrivilege", "SeLockMemoryPrivilege", 
            "SeMachineAccountPrivilege", "SeManageVolumePrivilege", "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege", 
            "SeRelabelPrivilege", "SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege", "SeRestorePrivilege", "SeSecurityPrivilege", 
            "SeShutdownPrivilege", "SeSyncAgentPrivilege", "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege", "SeSystemProfilePrivilege", 
            "SeSystemtimePrivilege", "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege", "SeTcbPrivilege", "SeTimeZonePrivilege", 
            "SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege", "SeUndockPrivilege", "SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege")]
        [String]$Privilege,

        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        $ProcessId = $PID,

        [switch]$Disable
        )

    begin {
        Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Privilege {
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    internal struct TokPriv1Luid {
        public int Count;
        public long Luid;
        public int Attr;
    }

    internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED    = 0x00000002;
    internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED   = 0x00000000;
    internal const int TOKEN_QUERY             = 0x00000008;
    internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;

    public static bool EnablePrivilege(long processHandle, string privilege, bool disable) {
        bool retVal;
        TokPriv1Luid tp;
        IntPtr hproc = new IntPtr(processHandle);
        IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
        retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
        tp.Count = 1;
        tp.Luid = 0;
        if(disable) { tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED; }
        else { tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED; }
        retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
        retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        return retVal;
    }
}
'@
    }
    process {
        try {
            $proc   = Get-Process -Id $ProcessId -ErrorAction Stop
            $name   = $proc.ProcessName
            $handle = $proc.Handle
            $action = if ($Disable) { 'Disabling' } else { 'Enabling' }
            Write-Verbose ("{0} '{1}' for process {2}" -f $action, $Privilege, $name)
            [Privilege]::EnablePrivilege($handle, $Privilege, [bool]$Disable)
        }
        catch {
            throw
        }
    }
}
```

and call both functions:

```
Enable-Privilege -Privilege SeSecurityPrivilege
Repair-DirectoryPermissions -Path 'D:\Blah'
```

Comment: The very great and neat solution from @Theo. Thank you for sharing it here.

Comment: Yeah this is amazing! My only comment would be also have it support files by adjusting the `New-Object` line: `if (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) {$newAcl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity} else {$newAcl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity}`