# Setting NTFS rights via P/S and getting Canonical Form error

Tags: powershell, ntfs, canonical-form

I have a PowerShell script to set up a user's folders with NTFS, Sharing and DFS.  All of it works, however I get this message when setting the NTFS rights.

Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified."
At C:\Users\Public\Documents\Scripts\Add-UserFolders.ps1:53 char:1

Code looks like this:

```
# NTFS Rights
$Acl = (Get-Item $UserFolder).GetAccessControl('Access')
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Username, 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -path $UserFolder -AclObject $Acl

$Acl = (Get-Item $ScanFolder).GetAccessControl('Access')
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Username, 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -path $ScanFolder -AclObject $Acl
```

My issue is the the first code block throws the error but the second code block does not even though the format is the same.  Running icacls Path\to\folder -verify show no error and the ACL is not modified to add the user object.

Comment: Why not use  `Get-help -Name `Get-Acl -Full` (vs Get-Item)?  Why not use the purposed built module for your use case. `Find-Module -Name '*NTFS*'`, which make this use case easier. Specifically the NTFSSecurity module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-Acl was the correct way to go, but I did not use the scripts shown above.  By running get-acl , I noticed that one object appeared in the wrong place.  Looking into the object, I determined that it was not needed and deleted it from the acl and now everything works just fine.

A VERY good explanation of canonical order is [here](https://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-acl-use.htm). Using that showed me where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

This error probably means the ACL is incorrectly ordered and to repair that, you can use my function
[Repair-DirectoryPermissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62645301/9898643)

Next I would advise using `Get-Acl`

Try:

```
# create the new access rule
# see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule
$rule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($Username, 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')

$Acl = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $UserFolder
$Acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$Acl | Set-Acl -LiteralPath $UserFolder

$Acl = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $ScanFolder
$Acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$Acl | Set-Acl -LiteralPath $ScanFolder
```